# Solve the equation using logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Equation
$$
e^{2x+1.21} = 114\cdot 4^x
$$
steps I've done so far.

- $2x + 1.21 = \ln(114) \cdot \ln(4) \cdot x$
- $x = (\ln(114) * \ln(4))/1.21$

I don't think I was allowed to move the $x$ from the right side to the left the way I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be 
$$2x+1.21=\ln(114)+(\ln 4)x.$$
(Recall that if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$.)

The rest should not be difficult. The displayed equation is *linear* in $x$. Bring the $x$ stuff to one side, and everything else to the other side.

Comment: I got x(2 + (ln4)) = ln(114)-1.21 which lead me to my final answer x =(ln(114)/(ln(4)) -3.21 and I'm still getting a wrong answer.

Comment: Yes, because it should be $x(2-\ln 4)=\ln(114)-1.21$, giving you $x=\dfrac{\ln(114)-1.21}{2-\ln 4}$.

Comment: Thank you! I need to refresh on my Algebra. Multiply and dividing polynomials is what I am lacking, right?

Comment: There was a slip about logarithms, easy to make. There was later a problem with a linear equation kind of problem basically like $7x+1-=3x+49$, except with more complicated numbers.  Ideally there should be no issue with these, they come up pretty often.